# What is this object?

Tags: archaeology

Can anyone help to identify these stone like objects.
Looks like it might have been used in some kind of armour maybe?

I know that there were a lot of battles in the field where it was found.

Location:
[East Meon, Hampshire, England.](https://maps.app.goo.gl/GYjZuGvRAzWx7XXDA)

[image][image][image]

Comment: [sea urchin fossil.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fhampshireculturaltrust%2F21835599646&psig=AOvVaw0iqLGfwjGogKy880Py569z&ust=1709406335175000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBMQjRxqFwoTCKCFuP7g04QDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP)

Comment: This link-only question is likely to be unsalvageable if the links go dead. Please consider [edit]ing your question to add the photo.

Comment: (Facetiously...) Some kind of scone? :)

Comment: Sorry I did not notice option to upload image directly here.

Comment: Removed the "weapons" tag because, as the answer revealed, it isn't one. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The item appears to me to be a form of sea urchin fossil. You can see a similar appearing one [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/hampshireculturaltrust/21835599646) which also was found in Hampshire England.

Another [here](http://collections.readingmuseum.org.uk/index.asp?page=record&mwsquery=(%7Bsearch%7D=*%7Bstone%7D)&filename=REDMG&hitsStart=261#:%7E:text=Cretaceous%2C%20from%20the%20chalk%20at%20St%20Mary%20Bourne%2C%20Hampshire&text=This%20sea%20urchin%20fossil%20is,or%20calcite%20in%20the%20chalk.) from the museum in Reading shows the overall shape, but the radial star patterns are less obvious:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it looks very similar; however, ours is flatter at the bottom and pointy at the top. This is why we thought it might have been used as some kind of weapon. The mystery is solved. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcinWasiluk Definitely an test of a sea urchin. There are quite a few species world wide, but as you are in the UK and you have an asymmetric one, there's a fairly good chance it is from a Heart urchin (*Echinocardium cordatum*). If this is so, one of the seams will be wider and less defined than the others.